# Two entities inside Core Data without relationship is bad design?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have the following entity:

```
class Payment: NSManagedObject {
   @NSManaged var name: String
   @NSManaged var amount: Double
}
```

On a given day I would have multiple payments. At the end of the day I want to take the total amount of payments and saved it somewhere:

```
class TotalPayment {
   @NSManaged var date: NSDate
   @NSManaged var total: Double
}
```

I need this because at some point I want to get the total of total payments per day for a particular period.

For example I want to take the total payments made in the last 30 days, or 100 days, so I need the sum of `TotalPayment::total` attribute for that period.

But I don't see how to set a relationship between these two. `TotalPayment` doesn't hold `Payment` objects, just a sum of `Payment::amount`.

Is this bad design ? If so, any ideas how to do it correctly ?

Comment: Why don't the payments have a date attribute that you can use for filtering? You can still create aggregated views, with or without relationships...

Comment: So then for a given period I should first calculate the sum of payments for every day in the period and then calculate the sum of sum of payments...Is my understanding correct ? So then I need only the Payment entity.

Comment: You wouldn't have 2 sums if you just had 1 entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a date attribute in your `Payment` entity, and that is all you need.

To sum for a certain period, just determine the start and end dates of the period you want to sum up, then fetch with this predicate:

```
NSPredicate(format: "date > %@ && date < %@", startDate, endDate)
```

Key value coding will help you calculating the sums efficiently with great convenience.

```
let sum = results.valueForKeyPath("@sum.amount") as! NSNumber
```